# How to send a sidekey securely to the subscriber for my channel

Tags: iota-network, security, masked-authenticated-messaging

Sending the `sideKey` and `channel-id` is important for new subscribers to read my stream. How can I securely transmit them over the network? Shouldn´t be the key exchange algorithm also quantum proof?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Key-Sharing technique like a Group Diffie-Hellman key agreement or you can mask (encrypt) the sideKey and channel-id using the Public keys of the receivers. As i know, there's a public-key cryptosystem called NTRU that is said it has resistance to quantum-computer-based attacks. So i think this is maybe the solution to this problem.

Comment: That doesn't answer the *how* or address the *quantum proofness*.

Comment: As i know, there's a  public-key cryptosystem called NTRU that is said it has resistance to quantum-computer-based attacks. So i think this is maybe the solution to this problem.

Comment: If you want to add information to your answer please [edit] your answer.

Answer (score 1):

[**Key exchange**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_exchange) is a problem not just for IOTA MAM but a lot of cryptographic algorithms especially for [**symmetric-key encryption**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm).

#### How can I securely transmit the keys?

To get the key from one actor to another, you have to establish a connection between the two, where no third party can interfere with the messages sent along this connection. Cryptographers call this a [**"secure channel"**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_channel). There are various techniques used to achieve this secure channel, though the well established ones ([RSA, ...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)) are not quantum proof.

#### Shouldn't be the key exchange algorithm also quantum proof?

Depending on your use case, you could use a quantum-nonresistant algorithm until quantum computers exist and upgrade after or immediately use [**Post-quantum algorithms**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-quantum_cryptography).

In the future, we might also be able to use something like [**Quantum key distribution**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_key_distribution) for key exchange.